# How to allow user login by either username or email using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have a node.js login system with passport but I am trying to figure out how to log in a user with either their username or email. I am only able to log in the user with email or username seperately. I don't know how to write the code to cater for both their username and email. So if a user wants to login with username, they can or if the wish to use their email, they also can. Here is my localstrategy code in my users.js file:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user, next){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
            }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
            }
        });
        });
    }));
```

And here's my module.exports in my user.js:

```
module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
    var query = {email: email};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

The above code only allows user to login with their email. I want users to have the opportunity to login with either their email or username.

Answer (score 2):

Just got into this situation, and I though I'll share my final code to verify user using either **username** or **email**:

```js
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async credentials => {
    const {
        email = undefined,
        username = undefined,
        password = undefined
    } = credentials

    if ((!!email && !!username) || (!email && !username)) {
        throw new Error('Should provide either email or username.')
    }

    if (!password) {
        throw new Error('Password is required.')
    }

    const user = await User.findOne(email ? { email } : { username })
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Credentials are invalid!')
    }

    if (!bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        throw new Error('Credentials are invalid!')
    }

    return user
}
```

So I am using this function to verify if the user provided valid credentials, and from my handler, I call the function on the **model** class.

Answer (score 1):

Expect *both* `username` and `password` within your authentication middleware and then proceed with whatever value you have found as the condition to find the user.

**Middleware example:**

```js
function authenticateUser(req, res, done) {

  let username = req.body.username,
      password = req.body.password,
      email    = req.body.email;
  let conditions = !!username ? {username: username} : {email: email};

  UserModel.findOne(conditions, (err, user) => {
    if (err)   return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(new Error('Incorrect username or email'));

    return user.comparePassword(password, user.password)
    .then(match => {
      if (match) return done();
      else       return done(new Error('Incorrect password'));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error) return done(new Error(`Unable to validated password. - ${error}`));
    });
  });

}
```

Now, a front-end developer — with the right documentation — can now actually use either the `username`, `email` or *both* (you will need a bit of JavaScript for both) when building login forms using your endpoint. Here is an example of using both:

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="/login">
  <input id="username-or-email" type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" required/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
// select the form element
let loginForm = document.querySelector('#login-form');

// add a form handler on submit
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", formHandler);

// validate and the set name attribute as appropriate
function formHandler() {
  /** W3C Email regex: (RFC5322) */
  const email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
  /** Must starts with a letter then can include underscores (_) & hyphens (-) */
  const username_regex = /^[a-zA-Z][\w-]+$/;

  let input = document.querySelector('#username-or-email');

  if (email_regex.test(input.value)) {
    // it is an email, send the value as an email
    input.setAttribute("name", "email");
  } else if (username_regex.test(input.value)) {
    // it is a username, send the value as a username
    input.setAttribute("name", "username");
  } else {
    // invalid email or username format, return an error message to user
  }

}
```

So you get to validate and set your dynamic input at the same time. Keep in mind that the regular expression should match your username and email data model as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getUserById` inside the callback of `getUserByEmail` so that both of the queries run for either `email` or `username`. If you specify `email`, then `emailOrUserName` will have the `email` value and then `User.getUserByEmail` will return the user and next it will proceed with `comparePassword`.

And if you have `username` then `emailOrUserName` will have the `username` value and then `User.getUserByEmail` will not return the user so, it executes `User.getUserById` and if the user is found there then it will proceed with `User.comparePassword` else it will return `Unknown user`

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(emailOrUserName, password, done) {
        User.getUserByEmail(emailOrUserName, function(err, user, next){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
              User.getUserById(emailOrUserName, function(err, user, next){
                   if(err) throw err;
                   if(!user){
                      return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
                   }
            }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
            }
        });
        });
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I use the code you posted above, I get an error in windows terminal:

throw er: // Unhandled 'error' event
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
at users.js

Comment: Have you imported `getUserById` in the file? Check that. And if your previous code was working then this should also work. This is the idea you can follow to achieve what you want.

Comment: With your code, I am able to login with email, but when I use username that's when I get the error. Let me check my module.exports code in my user.js to see if I referenced it correctly

Comment: This should work perfectly unless there is any other error. You can check it once and debug your code.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. See what's in my user.js:

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
    var query = {email: email};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
 var query1 = {id: id};
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

Answer (score 0):

Do this in local strategy

```
function(username, password, done) {
    var criteria = (username.indexOf('@') === -1) ? {username: username} : {email: username};
    User.findOne(criteria, function (err, user) { //implementation }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below can be used to allow your users to log in using either their username or email and password:

```js
if (!req.body.username && !req.body.email) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "All input is required, username/email is missing", 
        status: false });
    return;
}

if (!req.body.password) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "All input is required, password is missing", 
        status: false });
    return;
}
  
let whereClause = {};
if (req.body.email) {
    whereClause.email = req.body.email;
} else if (req.body.username) {
    whereClause.username = req.body.username.toLowerCase();
}

const user = await User.findOne({ where: whereClause });

// If user not found
if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found", status: false });
}
```

You can wrap it in a try-catch block for proper error handling.

Answer (score -1):

I add little more on the above answer shared by user7153178: Mine is related to the backend, using context.

Inside your Login component in the frontend, try to have these.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

then you will be needing this function on your form:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
const user = {
  email,
  password,
};

if (email === "" || password === "") {
  setError("Please fill in your credentials");
} else {
  loginUser(user, context.dispatch);
}
};
```

this is one of the input as part of your form

```
<Input
placeholder={"Email or Phone Number"}
name={"email"}
id={"email"}
value={email}
onChangeText={(text) => 
setEmail(text.toLowerCase())}
 />
```

In the backend write your post like that:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const user = await User.findOne(
{ $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { phone: 
req.body.email }] }
);

if (!user) {
return res.status(400).send("The user not found");
}

if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, 
user.passwordHash)) {
const token = jwt.sign(
  {
    userId: user.id,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  },
  secret,
  { expiresIn: "1d" }
);

res.status(200).send({ user: user.email, token: 
token });
} else {
res.status(400).send("password is wrong!");
}
});
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to make it more readable. Use code fences for the code portions.